# Laravel 5.7 Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So, I'm having some issues with getting some information from my database in Laravel. The thing is, I want to have a site settings table, with some global defaults.

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| option_name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| option_value | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Like this.. How do I get all the info with Laravels Eloquent?

```
select * from `options`;
> 1 | site_name | mysite.com
```

I want to be able to do

```
$options->site_name
```

in my controllers and views. Can't remember what this kind of thing is called, so I can't really search for it.. :(

**EDIT:**

Model class after request

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DNBOptions extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'dnb_options';
    protected $primaryKey = 'option_name';

    protected $fillable = [
        'option_name', 'option_value'
    ];
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Got answer on Laracast to use ->pluck() and cast to an (object) to get the result I was looking for.

> $option->site_name

[Link to Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-to-object)

Comment: Do you already have the Model class? So I can answer

Comment: What is the model name?

Comment: updated my question with model

Comment: In Laravel Eloquent you have to set the primary key the real table primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your App/Http/Controllers/Controller.php

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected $options;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->options = (object)DNBOptions::pluck('option_value', 'option_name')->toArray();
        \View::share('options', $this->options);
    }
}
```

In views:

```
{{ $options->site_name }}
```

In controllers:

```
$this->options->site_name
```

Comment: This is what I kinda looked for. I got an answer on Laracast to use ->pluck() and cast it as an (object). Result will be $options->site_name. Thank you, I'll mark your answer as solution to my question

Comment: I am agree. Replaced the answer with pluck.

Answer (score 1):

First create the Model. You can do it manually or with `artisan` in terminal :

```
php artisan make:model Option
```

This will create `App\Option` class. Then configure the Model in `app/Option.php` :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Option extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'options';
}
```

Now in any controller like `App\Http\Controllers\AnyController` you can use code :

```
use App\Option;

// Other codes ...

public function show($id) {
    $option = Option::find($id);
    echo $option->option_name; // print "site_name"
}
```

**EDIT AFTER OP GIVE NEW MODEL -------------**

So if you use model :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DNBOptions extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'dnb_options';
    protected $primaryKey = 'option_name';

    protected $fillable = [
        'option_name', 'option_value'
    ];
}
```

then in controller or view use :

```
$option = \App\DNBOptions::find('site_name');
echo $option->option_value;

// Get all
$options = \App\DNBOptions::all();
foreach($options as $option) {
    echo $option->option_name;
    echo $option->option_value;
}

// Print 1st
echo $options->first()->option_name;

// With where
$option = \App\DNBOptions::where('option_name', 'site_name')->first();
echo $option->option_value;
```

A full Controller - View example :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\DNBOptions;

class OptionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $options = DNBOptions::all();
        $data ['options'] => $options;
        return view('options.index', $data);
    }
}
```

And the View class is `resources/views/options/index.blade.php` :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@foreach($options as $option)
     {{ $option->site_name }}
     {{ $option->option_value }}
@endforeach
```

Use `@extends` if you have a layout template. And See Laravel Documentation for further information.

Comment: I don't want to force using the ID. I'm doing a Option::all() /Option::get() and after that I want to be able to use $option->site_name

Comment: You can loop with foreach, or get the first one only with `->first()`

Comment: In which location do you want to do that? Which view, just one or multiple?

Comment: You can use it at any place, Controller, Model, View, but in preference in Controllers Action (method) that will pass values to views after treatment. Or just sending one `$option` object to a view

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent Query :

```
$options = DB::table('options')->get();
```

get all info using this code:

```
@foreach($options as $option)
     {{ $option->site_name }}
     {{ $option->option_value }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

`DNBOptions::where('option_value', 'mysite.com')->get();`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-models

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: That's not what I'm asking for. In DNBOptions there'll be .. information about updates (option_name=is_live, option_value=false) and so on. Static things and so on

Comment: expand on the query as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller first add model name space:

```
use App\Option;

 ....
 ....

public function methodName($id) {
    $data['options'] = Option::all();
    return view('index',$data);
}
```

view located in `resources/views/` directory wich name is index.blade.php

or in blade :

```
@foreach($options as $option)
     {{ $option->site_name }}
     {{ $option->option_value }}
@endforeach
```